# AWS DynamoDB Scan and FilterExpression using array of hash values

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am having a hard time finding a useful example for a scan with FilterExpression on a DynamoDB table. I am using the javascript SDK in the browser.

I would like to scan my table and return only those records that have HASH field "UID" values within an array I pass to the Scan

Lets say I have an array of unique ids that are the hash field of my table
I would like to query these records from my DynamoDB table.

Something like below

```
var idsToSearch=['123','456','789'] //array of the HASH values I would like to retrieve
var tableToSearch = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var scanParams = {
  "TableName":"myAwsTable",  
  "AttributesToGet":['ID','COMMENTS','DATE'],  
  "FilterExpression":"'ID' in "+idsToSearch+"" 

}
tableToSearch.scan(scanParams), function(err,data){
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); //error handler
    else console.log(data); //success response
})
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should make use of the `IN` operator. It is also easier to use [Placeholders](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html) for attribute names and attribute values. **I would, however, advise against using a `Scan` in this case**. It sounds like you already have the hash key attribute values that you want to find, so it would make more sense to use [`BatchGetItem`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html).

Anyways, here is how you would do it in Java:

```java
ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec()
    .withFilterExpression("#idname in (:val1, :val2, :val3)")
    .withNameMap(ImmutableMap.of("#idname", "ID"))
    .withValueMap(ImmutableMap.of(":val1", "123", ":val2", "456", ":val23", "789"));
ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> = table.scan(scanSpec);
```

I would imagine using the Javascript SDK it would be something like this:

```javascript
var scanParams = {
  "TableName":"myAwsTable",
  "AttributesToGet": ['ID','COMMENTS','DATE'],
  "FilterExpression": '#idname in (:val1, :val2, :val3)',
  "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    '#idname': 'ID'
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ':val1': '123',
    ':val2': '456',
    ':val3': '789'
  }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful. I am wondering if there is a way to pass my array of HASH values into the query parameters

Comment: No, for [`Query`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html), you must provide a single hash key value to query on. You then narrow your results down on that hash key (with a range key condition or other attribute values).

Comment: Performance-wise, are you suggesting that BatchGetItem will more sense than a scan? In realty I could be requesting 1,000 items from table containing 50,000 item

Comment: Yes. [`Scan` reads every item in a table or a secondary index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Scan). Also, [In the case of a Scan operation, DynamoDB considers the size of the items that are evaluated, not the size of the items returned by the scan.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html#CapacityUnitCalculations)You should look at the [Guidelines for Query and Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScanGuidelines.html).

Comment: You will still need to batch those calls up since [If you request more than 100 items BatchGetItem will return a ValidationException with the message "Too many items requested for the BatchGetItem call"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html). It may be a better idea to evaluate your table design and see if their is a better access pattern to get your data.

Comment: I don't think this deserve green check. this is still static, not dynamic.

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue and figured it out by using [contains](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html) parameter

```
// Object stored in the DB looks like this: 
// [
//     'name' => 'myName',
//     'age' => '24',
//     'gender' => 'Male',
//     'visited' => [
//          'countries': ['Canada', 'USA', 'Japan', 'Australia'],
//          'last_trip': '2015/12/13',
//          'reviews_written': 20
//     ]
// 
// ];

$countries = ['Canada', 'USA', 'Japan', 'Australia'];

$paramToMatch = '24';

$client->query([
        'TableName'     => 'MyDyanmoDB',
        'KeyConditions' => [
            'age' => [
                'AttributeValueList' => [
                    $marshaler->marshalValue($paramToMatch)
                ],
                'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
            ]
        ],
        'ExpressionAttributeNames' => [
            '#visited'   => 'visited',
            '#countries' => 'countries'
        ],
        'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
            ':countries' => $marshaler->marshalValue($countries)
        ],
        'FilterExpression' => 'contains(:countries, #visited.#countries)',
]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I was able to use "scan" to get the items with a particular ID ("ContentID") in below example:

```
var params = {
    TableName: environment.ddbContentTableName,
    ProjectionExpression: "Title, ContentId, Link",
    FilterExpression: "ContentId in (:contentId1, :contentId2, :contentId3, :contentId4)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {":contentId1":102,":contentId2":104,":contentId3":103,":contentId4":101}
};

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
docClient.scan(params, onQuery);
```

I can then programmatically construct the FilterExpression and ExpressionAttributeValues based on known values e.g.

```
    // Create the FilterExpression and ExpressionAttributeValues
    var filterExpression =  "ContentId in ("; 

    var expressionAttributeValues = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < currentFavorites.length; i++) { 
        var contentIdName = ":contentId"+(i+1);
        
        if (i==0) {
            filterExpression = filterExpression + contentIdName;
        } else {
            filterExpression = filterExpression + ", " + contentIdName;
        }

        expressionAttributeValues[contentIdName] = currentFavorites[i];
    }

    filterExpression = filterExpression + ")";

    var params = {
        TableName: environment.ddbContentTableName,
        ProjectionExpression: "Title, ContentId, Link",
        FilterExpression: filterExpression,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expressionAttributeValues
    };

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    docClient.scan(params, onQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a dynamic solution, than having to manually put each of the parameter names into the conditional expression. 
Below is a solution:

```
List<String> valList= new ArrayList<String>(); // Populate the Values in a List    
StringJoiner valMap =  new StringJoiner(","); // This will be the dynamic Value Map

int i=1;

        table = dynamoDB.getTable(myTable);
        StringBuilder filterExpression = new StringBuilder();
        Map<String, Object> eav = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if(!valList.isEmpty())
        {
            for(String attrVal: valList)
             {
                eav.put(":val"+i, attrVal);
                valMap.add(":val"+i);
                i++;
            }   
            filterExpression.append("attrColName in ("+valMap.toString()+")"); //here attrColName is the DB attribute
        }

        ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> items;
            items = table.scan(
                filterExpression.toString(), //FilterExpression
                null, //ProjectionExpression - choose all columns
                null, //ExpressionAttributeNames - not used in this example
                eav);//ExpressionAttributeValues
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var params = {
TableName: "tableOne",
ProjectionExpression: "Title, ContentId, Link",
FilterExpression: "ContentId in (:contentIds)",
ExpressionAttributeValues: {":contentIds":[11,22,33,44,55]}
};

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
docClient.scan(params);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.