# How to get items from dynamodb using an array of primary keys?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the `documentClient` to work with `dynamodb`.

I have an array of the primary keys.

What method should I use, `Scan` or `Query` to get items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of primary key values, you should use the [`BatchGetItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) API. [`Query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) does not really help you are, and a [`Scan`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) is unneeded because you already know the primary keys to index into.

> The `BatchGetItem` operation returns the attributes of one or more items from one or more tables. You identify requested items by primary key.

Comment: Thank you! However, I am going to use Scana and the FilterExpression  because I have the secondary key in my table.

Comment: thank you for this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30220138/6108211